# Git stash does not discard the changes

Tags: git

When I freshly checkout a project from my git repo

I have a file that is in checked out state

I try to stash till, but does not work

I tried resetting even that did not work.

What should I do to get rid of this stubborn checkout

git status always gives

```
On branch mainline
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mainline'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   src/com/nandish/jungle/myi/MyiViewType.java

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: What does `git status` exactly say?

Comment: And it what way did stash not work?

Comment: Edited the question with status

Comment: Are you on windows by any chance?

Comment: +1 for windows - or perhaps mac - likely a case-sensitivity issue in directory or file names

Comment: This is seen on Mac OS

Comment: What about `git diff`? What are the changes reported?

Comment: @mgarciaisaia Yes, git diff shows difference but unable to stash it

Comment: @NandishA but is there a _real_ difference, or just formatting/line-ending issues? Do you have a `.gitattributes` file in the root of the repo? What happens if you `git checkout src/com/nandish/jungle/myi/MyiViewType.java`?